# Calculating $\phi(100)$ where $\phi$ is the totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, totient-function

---

**The Question:**

---

Calculate $\phi(100)$

---

**My Attempt:**

---

I attempted to calculate the totient function at the value 100, i.e.:

$$\phi(100)$$

To do this, I used the product rule of the totient function:

$\phi(ab)$ = $\phi(a)$ $\times$ $\phi(b)$

So $\phi(100)$ = $\phi(25)$ $\times$ $\phi(4)$

= $\phi(5)$ $\times$ $\phi(5)$ $\times$ $\phi(2)$ $\times$ $\phi(2)$

= 4 $\times$ 4 $\times$ 1 $\times$ 1

= 16.

---

**The Confusion (if you will)**

---

However, when I searched up the totient function of 100 online, it consistently came up with 40. This seems to me like a more appropriate answer, but I'm not quite sure where I went wrong on my attempt. Could you please tell me where I went wrong?

---

***Thanks!***

---

Comment: Read the product rule carefully. _All_ of it. You have missed a crucial part.

Comment: $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b)$ only if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so I think your problem came when doing $\phi(25)=\phi(5)\cdot\phi(5)$ and $\phi(4)=\phi(2)\cdot\phi(2)$

Comment: Wait, relatively prime part right? So my first line was correct ($\phi(100) = \phi(25) \times \phi(4)$) while in the second line the 5s are not co-prime and the 2s aren't - is that my mistake @Arthur?

Comment: Yes, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is the same as saying $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Your first line was correct.

Comment: @Gill That's the one, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, @Arthur cleared this up for me in the comments, so I'll answer my own question:

$\phi(ab)$ = $\phi(a)$ $\times$ $\phi(b)$, **only if a and b are co-prime**.

So, while $\phi(100)$ = $\phi(25)$ $\times$ $\phi(4)$ because 25 and 4 are co-primes, $\phi(100)$ = $\phi(5)$ $\times$ $\phi(5)$ $\times$ $\phi(2)$ $\times$ $\phi(2)$ is not true because **the 2s are not coprime, and the 5s are not co-prime either.**

So, $\phi(100)$ = $\phi(25)$ $\times$ $\phi(4)$.

$\phi(25)$ = 20 (We can evaluate this through the formula  $\phi(p^n) = p^{n-1}(p-1)$, so  $\phi(5^2) = 5^{1}(4) = 5 \times 4 = 20$.

$\phi(4)=2$.

$\implies \phi(100)$ = $20 \times 2= 40$.

*Thanks to @Arthur and @DreiCleaner for clearing this up, and @J.W.Tanner for suggesting some ways to make this answer better!*

Comment: So that's why $\phi(100)$ is not $16$; do you know why it's $40$?

Comment: Well the totient function of 4 is 2, the totient function of 25 is 20. 2 $\times$ 20 = 40. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: That is correct ($+1$).  Do you know a general formula for $\phi(p^n)$, which specializes to give $\phi(25)=20$ and $\phi(4)=2$?

Comment: Well, $\phi(p^n) = p^{n-1}(p-1)$. I can add that for further clarity, I suppose.

Comment: But now you have to ask, what *is* $\phi(25)$ and $\phi(4)$ now that you know what they *aren't*.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean @fleablood. I've evaluated $\phi(25)$ and $\phi(4)$ above...

Comment: Hmm... thee tag says you edited the 5 hours ago.  But my browser window didnt show me you had evaluated these at all.  Just that you knew why your first answer was wrong.  It also didn't show me J.W. Tanners first comment which wasexactly the same as mine.  But five hours earlier.

Comment: Ah, well I evaluated it in my answer. I suppose it was just a browser error.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, $5$ and $5$ are not coprime, so you cannot use the product rule there. Same for $2$ and $2$. I suggest simply counting directly, as it's rather small numbers involved.

There is, however, also a simple rule for $\phi(a^n)$ you can use, either at that stage for $\phi(4)$ and $\phi(25)$, or immediately for $100=10^2$. If you haven't seen that rule, here is a small pointer to get you started:

> How many numbers from 0 to 10 are coprime to 10? How about from 10 to 20? What about from 20 to 30? What about [and so on...]
>
> Finally, is there a difference between being coprime to 10 and coprime to 100?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... rule 1:

If $p$ is prime $\phi(p) = p-1$.  That should be clear as as $1$ to $p-1$ are all relatively prime to $p$.

Rule 2:

If $n = p^k$ then $\phi(p) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$.

Not so obvious on the outset but if you consider than all numbers between $1$ and $p^k-1$ are of the form $q*p + r; 0\le r < p$ than $p*p + r$ relatively prime if an only if $r\ne 0$ and so then numbers $q*p + 1, q*p+2, ....q*p+(n-1)$ are relatively prime while $q*p + 0$ is not.  For every $q$ there are $p-1$ of these $q*p + r; r\ne 0$ and the question remains how many $q$s are there?  Well, $q$ can be as little as $0$ for $n=1,...., p-1$ and as big as $p^{k-2}$ for $p^{k-1} +1=p*p^{k-1}+1,.., $ to $p^k-1 = p*p{k-1} + (p-1)$.  so there are $p^{k-1}$ possible $q$s and so there are $(p-1)\times p^{k-1}$ or $p^{k-1}(p-1)$ numbers relatively prime to $p^k$.

The final rule is

rule 3:  If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$.  This with the other rules can determine $\phi(n)$ for all positive integer $n$ by considering the prime factorization of $n$.  If $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ then $\phi (n) = \prod \phi(p_i^{k_i}) = \prod( (p-1)p_i^{k_i-1})$.

So $\phi (100) = \phi (4)\phi (25)=\phi(2^2) \phi(5^2) = (2-1)2^{2-1}(5-1)25^{2-1} = 2*20 = 40$.

Now the reason for rule 3: is similar two the first to rules but a bit more of a headache to derive.  But it can be done.

Here's *rough* argument:

Out of every $a$ numbers $\phi(a)$ of them will be relatively prime to $a$ and $(a-\phi(a))$ of them will not.

So out of $ab$ numbers $b\phi(a)$ of the will be relatively prime to $a$ and $(ab - b\phi(a)$ will not be.

Out of every $b$ numbers $\phi(b)$ of them will be relatively prime to $b$ and $(b-\phi(b))$ of them will not.

So out of $ab$ numbers $a\phi(b)$ of the will be relatively prime to $a$ and $(ab - a\phi(b))$ will not be.

And out of $ab$ numbers $(b-\phi(b))(a-\phi(a))$ will not be relatively prime to *either* $a$ nor $b$.

Using inclusion/exclusion

$\phi(ab) =$ the number of numbers relatively prime to $ab$ less than $ab=$

the number of numbers that are relatively prime to both $a$ and to $b=$

The total number of numbers up to $ab$ minus the numbers that are not relatively prime to $a$ minus the number that are not relatively prime to $b$ plus (to avoid double counting) the numbers number that are not relatively prime to either $=$

$ab - (a-\phi(a))b - (b-\phi(b))a + (a-\phi(a))(b-\phi(b) =$

$ab - ab +b\phi(a) -ab +a\phi(b) +ab - b\phi(a) -a\phi(b) + \phi(a)\phi(b) =$

$\phi(a)\phi(b)$

Ta-da.